# How to write an init script that will execute an existing start script in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: scripts, 20.04, services, init.d

my question similar to: [How to write an init script that will execute an existing start script?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72123/how-to-write-an-init-script-that-will-execute-an-existing-start-script)

However, that question is outdated and I like to know how I can do that in Ubuntu 20.04

This my try in init.d directory:

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          myrec
# Required-Start:    $all
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:
# Short-Description: your description here
### END INIT INFO

PATH=/home/ahmad/recordings
DESC="Recording audio output"
NAME=myrec
DAEMON=/home/ahmad/recordings/myrec.sh
PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME
```

- I would like to run it after all processes executed, so should I use a systemd service or the above is okay?
- Should I add other code to above or it runs my sh (`myrec.sh`) file?

In general What is a `hello world` for executing a simple bash (so that I can see the result) for ubuntu 20.04? Every thing I found in the web is outdated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two common ways to start a service on Ubuntu:

1. Making a service file in `/etc/init.d` directory.

You can check the existing ones as examples. There used to be a template file named `skeleton` which is no more exists. However you can find a basic example and more help by running `man init-d-script`.

After creating the file run `sudo update-rc.d myservice defaults` to install your service (here referred as `myservice`). refer to [update-rec.d](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/update-rc.d.8.html), Then you can start and stop your service using `sudo service myservice start`

2. The second and recommended or new one is creating a `SystemD` service.

To know the difference with the above check: [Difference between systemctl init.d and service](https://askubuntu.com/questions/911525/difference-between-systemctl-init-d-and-service)

Here is a simple example of how to create and run your service:

https://www.linode.com/docs/quick-answers/linux/start-service-at-boot/

You can also refer to his manual page for detailed descriptions of these two styles:

http://0pointer.de/public/systemd-man/daemon.html